# How to disable cookie check for public static files in .Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, .net-core

I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0`.

For every public static file that the client requests the debug log states:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[8] \n
>   AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.

Comment: If you want to restrict the access of the static files to authenticated user, then you need to validate the cookie and to pay the price. But if you want to make them publicly available, you could disable that check.

Comment: This is one of the reasons that static files are often served from a CDN.

Comment: @Daboul I could not find any way to disable it for static files only, any tips?

Comment: @Mise Where are your static files stored? If I believe MS doc, static files from wwwroot folder should be publicly available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.0#static-file-authorization

Comment: @Daboul They are pubically available (in wwwroot). Thats why it's so strange that a cookie check is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your `Startup` class and make sure the `UseStaticFiles` is executed before `UseAuthentication`. The order is relevant for the execution order in the ASP.NET Core pipeline. Otherwise the authentication is run before the static file execution will be able to handle the request.

```
class Startup {
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ...
       app.UseStaticFiles(...);
       ...
       app.UseAuthentication();
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed. It should be the case if the project has been created from MS template, but it should be verified.